# "The specified directory 'media/fa/FAF9-!C03' is not valid" Error when trying to open USB sticks!

Tags: usb, error-handling, flash-memory

I have an ARM-based computer(nanopi m1) that has 3 USB ports that all work good with other devices like mouse, keyboard, wireless dongle. but when I try any USB flash memories it doesn't work!

What's the problem and how can I fix?

The boards OS is a specified Debian Jessie. And the USB flash formats were FAT32 and I can open all of them in my laptop that has Debian Jessie.

This is the result of running `dmseg`:

```
[  216.222791] ehci_irq: highspeed device connect
[  216.500143] usb 4-1: new high-speed USB device number 3 using sunxi-ehci
[  216.654004] scsi1 : usb-storage 4-1:1.0
[  218.253422] scsi 1:0:0:0: Direct-Access     JetFlash Transcend 16GB   1100 PQ: 0 ANSI: 4
[  218.264961] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] 31703040 512-byte logical blocks: (16.2 GB/15.1 GiB)
[  218.274877] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
[  218.280407] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Mode Sense: 43 00 00 00
[  218.281318] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] No Caching mode page present
[  218.287508] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Assuming drive cache: write through
[  218.299272] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] No Caching mode page present
[  218.305591] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Assuming drive cache: write through
[  218.313695]  sda: sda1
[  218.320924] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] No Caching mode page present
[  218.327115] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Assuming drive cache: write through
[  218.334071] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

Comment: How to debug the problem: Look at output of `dmesg` or the syslog-file shortly after you plugged in the USB stick. The messages should tell you if the USB device itself is correctly recognized (or if it's a hardware problem), if the automounter (probably `usbmount`) is called, and what the automounter does. The path name `/media/fa/FAF9-!C03` looks fishy, possibly the automounter is misconfigured. You can mount the stick manually if a `/dev/sd*` device was successfully created.

Comment: How to mount it?
I am newbie in linux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partial answer:

As you can see from the log, your USB drive was recognized as block device `/dev/sda`, and it contains one partition, `/dev/sda1`. Look into the syslog (`/var/log/syslog*`) to see possible messages of the automounter.

You can mount a filesystem on a block device with the mount command (see `man mount` for lots of details). You need a (usually empty) directory as a location to mount it on. The directory `/media` typically contains such directories as mountpoints for removable medias, e.g. `/media/usb0` etc. There's also `/mnt`. Look at your directory structure (`ls`) to find something suitable.

You mount as root (typically with `sudo`) with a command like `mount /dev/sda1 /media/usb0`. You can also specify the type of the filesystem (e.g. `-t vfat`) if it's not recognized for some reason.

I don't know which automounter you have installed. On Debian, it's typically `usbmount`. Check with `dpkg -l usbmount` if it is installed. The configuration file for it is `/etc/usbmount/usbmount.conf`.

I'm a bit irritated by the repeated "no caching mode present" messages; possibly something else is misconfigured.

Comment: "usbmount" wasn't installed! and after installation the problem solved!
Thank you a lot dirkt!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with Raspbain OS on BananaPiM64. The problem was that the automounter did not have the permission to create the mount point directory in `/media/pi`. So I solved it by the below command.

```
sudo chmod 777 /media/pi
```